# Trigger startDrag for raphael

Tags: svg, raphael, drag

Imagine I have two circles on a raphaeljs paper: A and B.

B has been set up to be draggable by the normal drag function i.e. B.drag(onMove, onStart, onFinish)

On clicking A, I want to pragmatically trigger the dragging of B.

Is this possible by utilizing the already established drag function on B? (I first tried looking for a Element.startDrag() function or similar, but this doesn't seem to exist)

Further context:

I am working on a task manager. In the example above, B is a marker that shows the dueDate of a task on a timeline. A is a button that sits above B and when clicked confirms that the task has been completed. When a task is completed the user has to select the completeDate of the task (as this may differ from the dueDate). So, on confirmation the the task has been completed, the app creates a clone of B, let's call it C (which represents the completeDate).This has to be dragged along the timeline to show the correct completed date. I am trying to make the workflow smoother, so that when the task is confirmed (by clicking A), it clones B and is automatically in drag mode (i.e. it follows the mouse).

Comment: You certainly could structure your drag handlers in such a way that they could be invoked manually, but what is your intent exactly?  Will circle B to be dragged along a different path each click, or a constant path?  Is it to be attached to another object on drop?  There may be much easier ways to accomplish such behavior than hijacking drag and drop.

Comment: In my opinion you'd have to use a custom drag function for what you're trying to do.. if youre working on some sample code please post so expert people here, excluding myself ofcourse :D could have a look and help you out :)

Comment: thanks. i have added additional context above